# Добавление элементов в ChoiceBox

Tags: java, javafx, fxml

Как добавить элементы в ChoiceBox в самом fxml файле?

Answer (score 0):

Добавить 3 `label` в `choiceBox`

```
<ChoiceBox id="choiceBox">
    <Label text="One"/>
    <Label text="Two"/>
    <Label text="Three"/>
</ChoiceBox>
```